# Does "of what" phrase need to have commas?

Tags: commas

I came across this writing. I was told that the second version is grammatically correct.

1. Donald oversaw the construction, of what he would deem, a "fortress".
2. Donald oversaw the construction of what he would deem a "fortress".

Why do we not include commas? Thank you.

Comment: Punctuation is a matter of style, not grammar. Generally, style manuals recommend against separating a complement from its licensing construct.

Answer (score 1):

The commas should not be included.

The first comma separates a prepositional phrase from the rest of the sentence. This problem becomes evident when we replace the object of the preposition with a simple object like *house*:

> Donald oversaw the construction, of a house. (wrong)
>
> Donald oversaw the construction of a house. (right)

The second comma separates the indirect object of *deem* from the verb itself. This problem is clearer in a more straightforward usage of the word:

> He deems it, a fortress. (wrong)
>
> He deems it a fortress. (right)

Your sentence is a little more intricate than these examples because the object of the preposition is not *of* but instead a noun clause, and *deem* is not in a simple sentence but embedded in that clause. However, the same punctuation rules apply.

Additionally, the quotes around *fortress* are non-standard. Unless you are quoting the word from a particular source, quotes around a single word suggest a [mention of the word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction), while you are just using it.

Comment: Thank you for this. This makes more sense now. Now that you've shown that it's the object of the preposition, its a lot clearer now.